# Copy multiple parts of some cell to another worksheet (all in one step)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Imagine I have a .txt document with raw data like this:

```
20180214abcdfhkjvdafhkkjgbv trewfdgjklmbv
20180213fjgmhjlkjlkmghjdfdshkjlkjlkjlkjas
20180215qewwqretiumnbsfdljf erwuoiukjhjjk
```

but there are more than 23500 rows. I need to split that information in different columns, like this:

```
2018---02---14---abcd---fhkjvda---fhkkjg---bv ---trew---fdgjklmbv
2018---02---13---fjgm---hjlkjlk---mghjdf---dsh---kjlk---jlkjlkjas
2018---02---15---qeww---qretium---nbsfdl---jf ---erwu---oiukjhjjk
```

where --- means "another column" haha

This is what I did:

- First, I copied all the raw data to a worksheet in Excel
- Then, I splitted the information in another sheet like this:

  ```
     For i = 1 To lastRow
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sht1").Range("A" & (i + firstRow)).Value = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("rawData").Range("A" & i).Value, 1, 4)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sht1").Range("B" & (i + firstRow)).Value = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("rawData").Range("A" & i).Value, 5, 2)
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sht1").Range("C" & (i + firstRow)).Value = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("rawData").Range("A" & i).Value, 7, 1)
     Next
  ```

but it takes too long (like 10 minutes, because there are more than 23500 rows and then I make a table and do a lot of other things).

So, I need something like: "take this characters from all these cells and paste them in all these other cells". Something like this:

```
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sht1").Range("A" & (firstRow) & ":" & "A" & (firstRow + lastRow)).Value = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("rawData").Range("A" & 1 & ":" & "A" & lastRow).Value, 1, 4)
```

but that doesn't work.

It works to do something like:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sht1").Range("A" & (firstRow) & ":" & "A" & (firstRow + lastRow)).Value = 0
```

but, instead of "0", I would like to put the characters mentioned before (for example, Mid(...,8,12)

I couldn't find any solution and I really need it. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

Text-to-Columns seems an expedient method.

```
Option Explicit

Sub splitDogsBreakfast()
    With Worksheets("rawData")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            worksheets("sht1").cells(1, "A").resize(.rows.count, 1) = .value2
        end wth
    end with
    With Worksheets("sht1")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(12, 1), _
                                 Array(19, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(32, 1))
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The same command is available on the Data tab.

Comment: But I need to put the information of one cell (example, A1) to split it in multiple cells (example, B1:Z1)

Comment: So what you are saying is that you want to keep the original instead of overwriting it with the first segment ...?

Comment: I want to do this:

 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sht1").Range("A" & (firstRow) & ":" & "A" & (firstRow + lastRow)).Value = Mid(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("rawData").Range("A" & 1 & ":" & "A" & lastRow).Value, 1, 4)


I mean, copy the characters 9-12, for example, of range A1:A1000 in another sheet in the cells A1:A1000

And then the characters 12-19 of the range A1:A1000 from the first sheet to the cells B1:B1000 in the other sheet

Comment: So now you only want the first segment (e.g. *2018*) from the rawData worksheet put into the sht1 worksheet and discard the rest?

Comment: I have this: 20180214abcdfhkjvdafhkkjgbv trewfdgjklmbv in cell A1 of sheet "rawData". I want to paste it in the sheet "sht1" like this: A1: 2018, B1: 02, B2: 14, ...

Comment: Okay, so you need help copying the data from rawData to sht1 before splitting it up with texttocolumns.

Comment: Exactly. Like I mentioned in the main post, I did it with a for loop, but there are more than 23500 rows and it takes too long to compile all the code, and I need to do it faster

Comment: My bad, I didn't include that part originally 'cause I thought it was kinda basic (or could even be done manually). See my [edit] above.

Comment: @Accexcessel - If the answer was helpful and addressed the main issue please accept it as a reference for others and up-vote it for Jeeped effort

Comment: I didn't noticed Jeeped (LOL). @Accexcessel - please review your previous questions and provide some feedback to the users that spend their free time to help you. Even if the answers are not the ideal ones for you, you could accept the best ones that might benefit others reading the your posts, or at least upvote the ones that are being helpful (even partially) - it'll provide an incentive and motivation for the experts to help others like you

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! That worked fast!! But I don't understand what you are doing in this part of the code: With Worksheets("rawData")
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            worksheets("sht1").cells(1, "A").resize(.rows.count, 1) = .value2
        end with
    end with


Another thing, why do you use With instead of a for?

Comment: @Jeeped.  Suggest you change the second argument of your `Array` from `1` to `2` so as not to drop the leading zero's on the dates.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the `Range.Parse` Method would be useful, **except** it will drop any leading zero's.

To move this to another sheet, before you do the "split", merely copy the range from the old sheet to the new sheet, and then do the split on the new sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ParseSpecial()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
With wsSrc
    Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With


rSrc.Parse _
    parseline:="[xxxx][xx][xx][xxxx][xxxxxxx][xxxxxx][xxx][xxxx][xxxxxxxxxx]", _
    Destination:=wsSrc.Range("B1")

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe the third `[xx]` should be `[xxx]`.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for picking that up.  (Once I realized you meant third from the end, and not from the beginning).

Comment: Actually I meant *'the third element with two x's should have three x's'* but you got there all the same.

Comment: If I want to past it in another sheet, why Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2).Range("B1") doesn't work? How can I do it?

Comment: @Accexcessel `Range.Copy` method to copy to new sheet. Then `Range.Parse` method on the new sheet